# Excel 2016: adding number values in a row from cells with text and numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to add number values in a row where cells contain text and numbers; like "P1" or "S7" where I need to add the 1 and 7 into a total column.

I can extract the number values from individual cells using =RIGHT(V3,SEARCH("P",V3))+0, but can't figure out how to do that easily for row of 32 cells.

Example:

Comment: Please add your example and some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example to sum **D1** through **G1**,  use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(D1:G1,2,9999))
```

[image]

As you see, this formula discards the lead text character in each cell.

**EDIT#1:**

To add cells beginning with ***P*** or ***S*** only, use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(D1:G1,2,9999)*(LEFT(D1:G1,1)="P")) + SUMPRODUCT(--MID(D1:G1,2,9999)*(LEFT(D1:G1,1)="S"))
```

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student.  If I need to just isolate the cells that contain "P" or "S", could I wrap your solution in an IF statement?  The idea would be to exclude values in any other cells that don't contain those specific characters.  In the example shown above, I just want to sum the numbers in D1 and E1, but exclude the F1 and G1 cells because they don't contain the proper character.

Comment: @J.Czach  Sure!  check back later

Comment: @J.Czach  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 0):

You can place your formula on the first column of your row. Then when you copy the formula across your columns it will automatically reference the cell offset the same as V3 is offset from each other cell with formula.